# Is it possible rollback Azure storage table transactions so that I do not lose data?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am fairly new to Azure cloud development.

I have a function app coded in C# that:

1. Gets a record from a storage table
2. Deletes that record
3. Updates fields on that record (including the partition key)
4. inserts the new record into the storage table

I am experiencing data loss, when an exception is thrown, on the insert portion.

I am wondering how, if step 4 throws an exception, I can then rollback step 2. If that is not possible how would I prevent the data loss, as I'm unable to use the built in Table Operations that would replace the entity because I am changing the partition key?

I understand that the hard part in all of this to be the partition key update, as I know the system was designed so that each transaction or operation is operating on records with the same partition key.

I have looked through the Table Service REST API and looked at all the Table Operations I thought could be helpful:
[Insert Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/inserting-and-updating-entities)
Update Entity
Merge Entity
Insert or Update Entity
Insert or Replace Entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do transactions due to partition key. So you'll have to look at a solution outside of the table storage.

What you could do is create the record before deleting it. That way you're assured that you won't lose any data (as long as you make sure the request to create a record succeeded).

You could take it one step further by making it an async process. Having a storage queue or service bus queue up your message containing the information of the request and having a function app (or anything else) handle the requests. That way you can assure the request remains retryable in case any transient errors occur over a larger timespan.

Answer (score -2):

As per question, we are able to reproduce the data loss issue.
In table, have below highlighted record.
[image]

Once exception occurred on Insert data got loss as mentioned in question
[image]

> To update value of `PartitionKey` CosmosDb doesn't allow direct update to value of partitionkey. First we need to delete the record and then create new record with new partitionkey value.

To prevent data loss using built in TableOperations you can perform/call Execute() once prior steps got completed successfully.

```
TableOperation delOperation = TableOperation.Delete(getBatchCustomer);
```

You can clone or create a deep copy of first object using copy constructor.

```
public Customer(Customer customer)
{
    PartitionKey = customer.PartitionKey;
    RowKey = customer.RowKey;
    customerName = customer.customerName;
}
```

Creating copy of the object

```
Customer c = new(getCustomer)
{
    PartitionKey = "India"
};
```

In step 4 mentioned in question by you is completed successfully then we can commit delete operation.

Got exception on insert step

[image]

but when looked data table no data has been lost.

[image]

Below is code snippet to prevent data loss.

```
TableOperation _insOperation = TableOperation.Insert(c);
var insResult = _table.Execute(_insOperation);
if (insResult.HttpStatusCode == 204)
{
    var delResult = _table.Execute(delOperation);
}
```

Comment: No need to "reproduce" OP's issue. Also, as I mentioned to you elsewhere, please stop posting images of text - as a reminder of the many reasons why you need formatted text, please read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for your input – could you be more specific what is the issue with this post? Secondly, I prefer to reproduce the OP issue, so I am sure of the solution I provide. Let me know if you have a better approach.

Comment: Just note that this site isn't company tech support, so there's no need to talk about recreating an issue (though it's fine to do so). The most important thing is to provide  a clear answer and succinct explanation (look at the accepted answer). And lastly, the OP's question contains no specifics: no code, no clarification if this is being applied to Storage or Cosmos DB (with Table API). As written (in my opinion) the question needs improvement before *anything* can be offered.